# BrazosUI No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/brazos-open/service/brazos/version] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Tags: activiti, brazos

I'm trying to install the vanilla BrazosUI developer edition 5.1.0 sample web app by following the official instructions and building the .war package with maven.
When I deploy the web app on tomcat and try to open the version uri- http://localhost:8080/brazos-open/service/brazos/version
I get the following warning in the Catalina logs:

```
03-May-2017 17:25:38.260 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/brazos-open/service/brazos/version] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

I'm using Maven 3.5.0, Tomcat 8.5.14, JVM 1.8.0_121-b13 on Windows 10 32bit.

Has anyone run into this issue before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There was a defect in the 5.1 release where a required bean was not declared.
To resolve, you need to:

```
Add the following to the sample app DispatcherServletConfiguration.java

import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
..
..
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This defect has been resolved in the [Brazos UI 5.1.1 release](https://support.bp-3.com/hc/en-us/articles/227835647) (registration and login required). Full release notes detailing all of the fixes and improvements can be found [here](https://support.bp-3.com/hc/en-us/articles/204687988).